# No rtp: Asterisk 11 + webRTC + CentOS 6

Tags: linux, centos

I installed Asterisk 11 on a CentOS 6 machine and tried to run a simple js script with jsSIP for making a voice call inside my LAN. However, **Asterisk doesn't seem to deliver the RTP packets since they don't appear on the CLI debugging**, so my call ends abruptly. Back on the jsSIP script, the audio stream received is null.

I followed this tutorial for the configuration: http://forums.digium.com/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=90167.
I installed libsrtp, so when I make the menuselect for Asterisk, the res_srtp option is enabled.

Which can be the causes for this? Or has anybody here got a flawless tutorial for installing Asterisk + WebRTC painfree? Regardless of the Linux distribution nor the Asterisk version .....

Here I leave my conf files and SIP debugging: http://pastebin.com/Kd3LPZJp

Thanks in advance ....

Answer (score 0):

This usually means that you have websocket set properly but the RTP/webrtc is not configured correctly (DTLS, SRTP handling).

Make sure that your webrtc extension looks like this:

```
[9999]
secret=9999
context=internal
host=dynamic
trustrpid=yes
sendrpid=no
type=peer
qualify=yes
qualifyfreq=600
transport=ws,wss
encryption=yes
avpf=yes
icesupport=yes
directmedia=no
dtlsenable=yes
disallow=all
allow=ulaw
nat=yes
dtlsenable=yes
dtlscertfile=/etc/asterisk/certificate/cert.pem
dtlsprivatekey=/etc/asterisk/certificate/key.pem
dtlscafile=/etc/asterisk/certificate/key/pem
dtlssetup=actpass
```

rtp.conf should look like this:

```
[general]
rtpstart=10000
rtpend=20000
icesupport=yes
;rtpchecksums=no
;strictrtp=no
stunaddr=stun.l.google.com:19302
```

Here you can find a detailed guide about [WebRTC configuration for Asterisk](https://www.mizu-voip.com/Support/Wiki/tabid/99/Default.aspx?topic=Asterisk%20WebRTC).

I would recommend to use the latest Asterisk (v.13) because a lot of improvements have been done for WebRTC recently.